# Cannot Access Memory At 0xe, kdbg on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, kdbg

I am studying book by Jeff Duntemann: Step by Step Assembly. Here is the source code provided:

```
SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data

    EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
    EatLen: equ $-EatMsg    

SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data 

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code

global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
    nop         ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
    mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov ecx,EatMsg      ; Pass offset of the message
    mov edx,EatLen      ; Pass the length of the message
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call

    MOV eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
    mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero 
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit running on VirtualBoxVM on top of 64 bit MacOS Yosemite.

I am calling:

```
kdbg eatsyscall
```

to launch KDBG.

In **watches** section I have 2 Expressions:**EatMsg** and **EatLen**

When I run the code using KDBG for EatMsg I see: **544497989** but for EatLen I see: **Cannot Access Memory At 0xe**

I have 2 questions:

What is this 544497989 value and why for EatLen I see the "Cannot Access" message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`544497989` is the address of `EatMsg`, it's just the memory location, i.e. some huge number. If you know C or C++, it's the equivalent of `&eatMsg` if your declaration is `char * eatMsg = "Eat at Joe's!";`

`EatLen` is the length of the `EatMsg`: `$` stands for "address at this point", which is the next location after all bytes of `EatMsg`. So `$-EatMsg` is "address after all bytes of `EatMsg` minus address of beginning of `EatMsg`" = "length of `EatMsg`" = 14 decimal = 0x0E hexadecimal.

Your debugger is likely interpreting this length as an address. Small values such as these cannot be referenced as addresses. You should display this merely as a value, not interpret is as address.

Comment: But 544497989 is not power of 2. Should not the address be power of 2?

Comment: No not at all. For some data and architectures a *multiple* of 2 (or 4, or 8) is required but for `db` this isn't the case.

Comment: Actually, 544497989 (decimal), expresed as hex is 20746145h - the ascii codes for space, 't', 'a', 'E' - it appears "backwards" because multi-byte values are stored "little-endian". If you examined it a byte at a time it would appear in the "right" order.

Comment: @FrankKotler Nice! Indeed OP is likely showing the contents of `EatMsg` rather than the address.